# Access denined to Administrator on Windows7 Home edition

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I have Windows7 Home edition on my home pc. I am the administrator of the machine. I recently changed my own password from control panel and changed permissions for another user. Since then I am getting access denied on some of the files I had created myself in a folder named C:\data. The file (dbmaintain.dll created by me using Visual Stidio 2008 C++) shows that my userid has Full Control and also that I have ownership of the object. Yet I cannot make a copy of this file from command prompt or windows explorer running in administrative mode. There are serveral other files in the same folder which have the same problem.

Comment: What is your question? How to change ownership, other ways to copy files? Why different folders have different permissions?